# What's the vocal technique called when the voice of the singer goes momentarily very high? Examples inside

Tags: voice

I have to give examples since there's pretty much no good way to describe this with words.

It's basically when a singer's voice shifts to a very high pitch for a short time, intentionally or not, at the end of a phrase or in between phrases.

Maybe it doesn't have a particular name and it's just a phenomenon that happens while singing, but it sounds good. Thanks in advance

Comment: If it's unintentional it's not a technique.  It's a sign that the singer is not well trained.

Comment: Tempted to say "Yodelling"   :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi and welcome to the Music stack exchange. What you are referring to in your examples is not so much a technique as much as it is a phenomenon known as "[Passaggio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passaggio)" or, more commonly, a "[Voice Break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_break)."

It occurs when the human voice transitions between different [vocal registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_register) and is essentially the same phenomenon that some teenagers experience unintentionally, as a 'voice crack,' when they are going through puberty...

[This article](http://www.leadvocals.ca/background/voice-break-and-switching-vocal-registers) on voice breaks and switching vocal registers may be helpful...

Many professional singers train painstakingly in order to achieve seamless transitions between vocal registers during the Passaggio. It is mainly in pop-music where one will hear the voice breaks emphasized for a bit of an extra novelty within the vocal performance.